# Handling dependencies when installing windows service with ServiceInstaller/ServiceProcessInstaller

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-services, dependencies, installation

I'm trying to build a self-installable Windows Service. I have an installer class defined like this:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    public MyServiceInstaller()
    {
        var serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller
            {
                Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem
            };

        var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller
            {
                DisplayName = "MyService",
                StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic,
                ServiceName = "MyService",
                Description = "My Service Description"
            };

        Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
        Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
    }
}
```

Here's a code I use to perform installation:

```
public void Install()
{
    using (var assemblyInstaller = new AssemblyInstaller(
      typeof(MyService).Assembly, 
      null) { 
        UseNewContext = true 
      })
    {
        var state = new Hashtable();
        try
        {
            assemblyInstaller.Install(state);
            assemblyInstaller.Commit(state);
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                assemblyInstaller.Rollback(state);
            }
            catch {}

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

When I trigger installation from my ASP.NET application, the assembly containing my Windows Service is installed somewhere to:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\xxxxxxx\25c14c59\a945a1e6\assembly\dl3\abf52138\74461ad8_8d5bce01\MyService.EXE
```

The problem is, this assembly is the only file installed.

**Questions:**

1. How do I also include assemblies my assembly depends on?
2. How do I also include my app.config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by not using the installer at all. Instead, I use WMI (`Win32_Service`) to register my service and then it just runs from within original location. Here's a relevant [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28161/Using-WMI-to-manipulate-services-Install-Uninstall) at codeproject.